# Split and write in cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I get some unclean data from a text file, and in the text file, I process it as per the data in the VBA script, which gives the following output.

This is the Raw String.

```
1* student 1*2018-01-01*1*1234122
2* student 2*2017-01-01*1*54654654234
3* student 3*2015-01-01*4*54234654654
4* student 4*2012-01-01*5*546542345654
```

I wanted the output in different cells, as mentioned below in any open worksheet in excel.

| Roll No | Student Name | Date of Birth | class | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | student 1 | 2018-01-01 | 1 | 1234122 |
| 2 | student 2 | 2017-01-01 | 1 | 54654654234 |
| 3 | student 3 | 2015-01-01 | 4 | 54234654654 |
| 4 | student 4 | 2012-01-01 | 5 | 546542345654 |

I tried various sources but couldn't get the expected output.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Split text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)

Comment: What 'sources' did you attempt? Have you looked at Text-To-Columns?

Comment: Actually, the data is scrapped from the emails, I VBA script is written to clean and add * as a delimiter to the string. So from VBA, I need to get this output.

Comment: You can paste all the raw strings in **Col A** and then use **Text To Columns** from VBA on **Col A**. And if you want to handle one string at a time then use [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)

Comment: @SiddharthRout. Thank you for the help. I am currently using the text to column, but I wanted to explore if there is any way that it can be done automatically.

Comment: Yes. Liek I mentioned, you cna use SPLIT. See the answer posted below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It assumes that the whole text you show is in a single cell, not in different linens. But the above way will also deal with a single row:

```
Sub extractTextDelimSep()
   Dim x As String, arr, arrLine, arrFin, cols As Long, i As Long, j As Long
   x = "1* student 1*2018-01-01*1*1234122" & vbCr & _
        "2* student 2*2017-01-01*1*54654654234" & vbCr & _
        "3* student 3*2015-01-01*4*54234654654" & vbCr & _
        "4* student 4*2012-01-01*5*546542345654"
    arr = Split(x, vbCr) 'split the rows
    cols = UBound(Split(arr(0), "*")) + 1 'determine the columns number per row
    ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) + 1, 1 To cols) 'ReDim the final array
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arrLine = Split(Replace(arr(i), " ", ""), "*")
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrLine)
            arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrLine(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Instead using `x` as a built string you my have the string in a cell and you can use `x = ActiveCell.value`.

It is easy to transform the above code in a function, too...

**Edited**:

You can use the next function:

```
Function extractTextDelimSep(x As String) As Variant
   Dim arr, arrLine, arrFin, cols As Long, i As Long, j As Long
   
    arr = Split(x, vbCr)
    cols = UBound(Split(arr(0), "*")) + 1
    ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) + 1, 1 To cols)
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arrLine = Split(Replace(arr(i), " ", ""), "*")
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrLine)
            arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrLine(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    extractTextDelimSep = arrFin
End Function
```

If everything is in the same cell (in column A:A), you should call it in the next way:

```
Sub TestextractTextDelimSep()
   Dim x As String, arr

    x = ActiveCell.Value
    arr = extractTextDelimSep(x)
    'drop the array content at once:
    Range("B" & ActiveCell.row).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

If the string is distributed one line of a (different) cell, you can use:

```
Sub TestextractTextDelimSepRange()
   Dim lastR As Long, arr, i As Long

     lastR = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     For i = 1 To lastR
          arr = extractTextDelimSep(Range("A" & i).Value)
          Range("B" & i).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
     Next i
End Sub
```

For this last case, in Excel 365 it can be used as UDF function, being called from the cell as formula:

```
  =extractTextDelimSep(A1) 'in A1 should be the line to be split
```